# Placing a caret inside a span element inside a contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, caret

I am developing a text editor. I have a content editable `<div>`, inside which there are going to be placed `<span>` elements with the actual style properties. 
Now, I know how to place a caret inside these span elements, but once I start to type, the text is being printed outside the span, inside the div itself.

Here's the relevant code for caret placement:

```
var rs = $( "#textEntry" ).insert( "span" ).set( "style" , style );

            sel = window.getSelection();

            sel.collapse( rs[ 0 ] , 0 );

            rs[ 0 ].focus();
```

Where `rs[ 0 ]` is the current span element.

How can I get over this behavior?

P.S. `$` is not a jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with this, it seems that the solution is as follows:

It was necessary to add some inner text, then set the caret on the element's first child, which is the TEXT node, then remove the text. The caret will stay at the position and voila! it works.

```
var rs = $( "#textEntry" ).insert( "span" ).set( "style" , style ).html( "a" );

rs[ 0 ].focus();
if ( document.selection ) {
    sel = document.selection.createRange();
    sel.moveStart( 'character' , 0 );
    sel.select();
}
else{
    sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.collapse( rs[ 0 ].firstChild , 0 );
}

rs.html( "" , true );
```

I'd be glad to see other solutions, guys!